# System.Web.Http.Results.OkResult vs Content(HttpStatusCode.OK)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponse

In Web Api 2 I can return a 200 in two ways.

`return Ok()` or `return Ok("Some value")`

Or

`return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Some value")` this can have any value included, along with formatters and some other parameters.

I know that `return Content(...)` supports all `HttpStatusCodes` so it will be used for responses like `NoContent` where there is no `return NoContent()`

Is `return Ok()`  just a shortcut for `return Content(..)`?

Comment: You should also be able to do `return Ok("some value")` which returns an `OkNegotiatedContentResult<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `return Ok()` just a shortcut for `return Content(..)`?

No

If you look at the methods in question you will see what they return `IHttpActionResult` derived classes

```
protected internal virtual NegotiatedContentResult<T> Content<T>(HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value);        
protected internal FormattedContentResult<T> Content<T>(HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value, MediaTypeFormatter formatter);        
protected internal virtual FormattedContentResult<T> Content<T>(HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value, MediaTypeFormatter formatter, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType);    
protected internal FormattedContentResult<T> Content<T>(HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value, MediaTypeFormatter formatter, string mediaType);    
protected internal virtual OkResult Ok();
protected internal virtual OkNegotiatedContentResult<T> Ok<T>(T content);
```

Each one of the return types are unrelated to each other except for the fact that they are derived from `IHttpActionResult`.

Comment: I went into the .net source code and saw the various different types returned, but from the callers side is there any difference?